# Locking Failed! with pipenv lock --clear

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile, pipenv-install

So everything was working correctly until I tried to install the "requests" library for flask. In my virtual environment I ran "pipenv install requests" and got this fun error message:

```
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Mtayl/OneDrive/Desktop/aA-work/FridgeFinder/FridgeFinder/fridgefinder/backend/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 100, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement(
pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'-lembic'": Expected W:(abcd...)
```

I have looked all over the interwebs and cannot find anything that leads to a solution. The best I have been able to find is that somewhere, in a file, there exists '-lembic' where I am assuming it should be either ~lembic or alembic. I have tried using "pipenv lock --clear" but I get the same message. I have even tried switching git branches to get around this but to no avail. Any help would be seriously appreciated.

If the full trace is needed I will post it, but that seems to be where the trace ends.